# Android ListView scrolls over ActionBar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am having a problem where I am populating a ListView with a HashMap, but when the data appears, the ListView appears over the ActionBar. I am using Fragments as well if that makes a difference. Below is the code for the ActionBar, ListView adapter, and a screenshot of my issue. Let me know if there is anymore information that you need.

ListView code:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ForumIndex.getInstance(), categories,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "title" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

ActionBar code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
        .setText("Categories")
        .setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener(this, Categories.class.getName()));
actionBar.addTab(tab);

tab = actionBar.newTab()
        .setText("Most Recent")
        .setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener(this, MostRecent.class.getName()));
actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

MostRecent Class Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Sample Image:

[image]

Comment: In older version ActionBar(Compat or Sherlock) is floating above the content view.

Comment: Yes, the floating only appears when using devices in compatibility mode. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Hmm, at the moment what I can think of is setting listview a top margin to the height of the actionbar. Like: retrieving actionbar height, and adding the same value as top margin to layout params of the listview. Don't forget to check API level to make sure you really need to set the margin.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. The problem was that the way I was adding my fragments was using the Android content instead of using my own layout.

I changed:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
```

To:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, and am currently passing android.R.id.content as first arg to fragmentTransaction.add. However, it's not clear from the material you posted (unless I am missing something of course) where exactly your replacement id is coming from, it's not an ID of any layout element you posted... Could you elaborate? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define padding that is `android:paddingTop` in for the listview.